# Disable a ribbon button with a plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm working on CRM 2011 (newbie...) and created a plugin that checks if incidents have activity records. If there are no activity records, the incident cannot be resolved.

I have a custom button launchin a dialog asking few things to the user and then setting the incident status to resolved.

What I would like is for this button to be disabled as long as there are no activity records...

How the hell can I do that??

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a rule that can be set for a ribbon button.

[These are the rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334682.aspx) that you can set on a ribbon button and I can't see one that allows you to disable based on a related entity count.

I use [this](http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/) when editing any ribbons so i'd maybe have a play with that to see if you can do what you need it to do.

My hunch would be to do a fetch query as the first step in your Dialog, and if that returns a result of 0 ( ie the query finds related activity records ) to end the Dialog.

Comment: This is great ! Thank you very much !

Just one more question, do you happen to know if I can add a personnalized message explaining to this user why the dialog ends?

Again, thanks !

Comment: From looking at Ckellers answer, it seems that in the link i put in my answer there is a [Custom Rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309433.aspx) type where, based on javascript you can decide to return true or false based on your own logic, this would give you your behaviour of disabled if no activity records.  If you just want to output a message before ending the dialog just use a prompt and response. Put your message in but don't allow a response type.

Comment: Ok guys, I've tried both and decided to use the dialog, to stay in the same logic as the rest of my solution. Thanks a lot !

Comment: +1 for the link to the visual ribbon editor.  It looks very promising.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a plugin. Plugins are executed on the server side.

What you are trying to achieve is to change the UI, according to a specific condition. You could use a custom [`EnableRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328073.aspx) for this. In this rule you could reference a [`CustomRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309433.aspx) which is basically a reference to a JavaScript function in a web resource. In this script you could evaluate the context (FetchXml request / OData) and decide whether the rule should evaluate to true/false and therefore to enable/disable the ribbon element.

Comment: Right, it sounds like a good way to do it as well. I'll try that too.

Thank you